# discord bot terminal: handle_response() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, arguments, bots

So im trying to make a discord bot, after going through issues with intent I ended up pip installing an older version of discord with this code: "pip install -U discord==1.7.3 pip install -U discord.py==1.7.3". With my bot finally online, I get this message in the terminal: "handle_response() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" here is my :responses tab:
import random
from discord import Message
here is the responses tab:

```
import random
from discord import Message


def handle_response() -> str:
    p_message = Message.lower()
    
    if p_message == 'hey':
        return 'hello there'
    
    if p_message == 'd20':
        return str(random.randint(1, 20))
    
    if p_message == '!help':
        return "'what now?'"
```

here is the bot itself:

```
from http import client
import discord
import responses



TOKEN = 'redacted' 
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await  message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:    
        print(e)
        
def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'redacted'
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
     print(f'{client.user} has awakend!') 
     
     
     @client.event
     async def on_message(message):
         if message.author == client.user:
             return
         username = str(message.author) 
         user_message = str(message.content)
         channel = str(message.channel)
         
         print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")
         if user_message[0] == '^':
             user_message = user_message[1:]
             await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
         else:    
             await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
             
    
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

I am using VSCode
please help:
Mahalo in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove and regenerate your bot token ASAP!
2. Discord.py 1.7.3 is using the Discord API v7, which has been decommissioned since 01/01/2023, using it will only cause more issues. Intents are now required from discord. Update to the newest available version.
3. You are calling your `handle_response` function with an argument, but it does not actually accept any arguments, what you probably meant was something like this:

```py
def handle_response(p_message: discord.Message) -> str:
    p_message = p_message.lower()
    
    if p_message == 'hey':
        return 'hello there'
    
    # etc
```

That being said, there is a bit more wrong with the way you are handling things right now. I would suggest looking at a basic example on how to get your bot running and going from there: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py